# Conditional update of SQL table with JOIN

Tags: sql, postgresql

Let's say you have tables:

```
CREATE TABLE TABLE1 (ID INTEGER PRIMARY KEY, VAL INT, CONDITION INT);
CREATE TABLE TABLE2 (ID INTEGER PRIMARY KEY, VAL INT, CONDITION INT);
```

with data:

```
INSERT INTO TABLE1 VALUES (0, 0, 100);
```

and

```
INSERT INTO TABLE2 VALUES
(0, 2, 100),
(1, 1, 100),
(3, 3, 100)
```

What will in TABLE1 after this query and why?

```
UPDATE TABLE1 SET VAL = SOURCE.VAL 
FROM TABLE2 SOURCE 
WHERE TABLE1.CONDITION = SOURCE.CONDITION
```

I got:

```
0;2;100
```

Does this mean that RDBMS executed `UPDATE` operation several times and I see only final result? Or it updates `VAL` only once?

Explain:

```
"Update on table1  (cost=270.68..562.65 rows=18818 width=24)"
"  ->  Merge Join  (cost=270.68..562.65 rows=18818 width=24)"
"        Merge Cond: (table1.condition = source.condition)"
"        ->  Sort  (cost=135.34..140.19 rows=1940 width=14)"
"              Sort Key: table1.condition"
"              ->  Seq Scan on table1  (cost=0.00..29.40 rows=1940 width=14)"
"        ->  Sort  (cost=135.34..140.19 rows=1940 width=14)"
"              Sort Key: source.condition"
"              ->  Seq Scan on table2 source  (cost=0.00..29.40 rows=1940 width=14)"
```

I used PostgreSQL.

Comment: Try SET VAL = SOURCE.VAL + 100

Comment: @jarlh, got `0;102;100`. But how RDBMS chooses which row from `TABLE2` to use? Does it get first row and skips others?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the [documentation](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/sql-update.html):

> a target row shouldn't join to more than one row from the other table(s). If it does, then only one of the join rows will be used to update the target row, but which one will be used is not readily predictable.

So the behaviour you see is exactly what is supposed to happen.

Answer (score 1):

Your question seems to be about what happens when there are multiple matches in the tables being updated.  Only one value gets set in the output.  An arbitrary matching row is used for the update.

The [documentation](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.4/static/sql-update.html) explains what happens:

> **Notes**
>
> When a FROM clause is present, what essentially happens is that the
>   target table is joined to the tables mentioned in the from_list, and
>   each output row of the join represents an update operation for the
>   target table. When using FROM you should ensure that the join produces
>   at most one output row for each row to be modified. In other words, a
>   target row shouldn't join to more than one row from the other
>   table(s). If it does, then only one of the join rows will be used to
>   update the target row, but which one will be used is not readily
>   predictable.
>
> Because of this indeterminacy, referencing other tables only within
>   sub-selects is safer, though often harder to read and slower than
>   using a join.

Answer (score 0):

It depends on the target. 
In this case, when tables are concerned, it will choose a single record match (mainly the first) and use that.
You can verify it by creating a trigger on Table1 and mark how many times a record was changed.
If the target wasn't a table but a variable, then the update would happen per each row. This is a fast way to concatenate values for instance.